# PHP Error : Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I want when I choose some value in a Select box to display a string for a number of times for example if I choosed the value 2 it will display a string twice.

this is the code I tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkIt()
{
    var getNum = document.getElementById("numb").value;

    //this_file.php ... im specifying for just. you specify this full code in any of file and specify the whole url path
    location.href="this_file.php?countIt="+getNum;
}
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .centrer
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        font-size:24px;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <select name="nombres" id="numb" onchange="checkIt();">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

<?php
if($_REQUEST["countIt"])
{
    $displayTimes = $_REQUEST["countIt"]; 
}
?>
   <div class="centrer">
    <?php
        $s = "Hello World! <br/>";
        for($i=0; $i<$displayTimes; $i++)
            echo $s;
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but I have a problem :

> Notice: Undefined variable: displayTimes in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\site\Untitled-1.php on line 43

notice that the line 43 is : `for($i=0; $i<$displayTimes; $i++)`

and also another problem that when I select the "1" Value it does anything, and also when I select other value the selected value in the select box still the value "1" and I have another question isn't there any other way to do this without using JS only by using PHP ?

Comment: Well `$displayTimes` is undefined as php states

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$displayTimes` would only be declared if the condition was met, it was caused by the following :

```
if($_REQUEST["countIt"]) <------------------- Condition 
{
    $displayTimes = $_REQUEST["countIt"];
}
```

Replace the above with :

```
$displayTimes = isset($_REQUEST["countIt"]) ? $_REQUEST["countIt"] : 0;
```

Comment: And the next bug OP will find is that his/her file isn't named **this_file.php** :)

Comment: @Baba what is the role of isset ?

Comment: [isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: @Baba thanks for your help but I still have the problem that when I select the "1" Value it does anything, and also when I select other value the selected value in the select box still the value "1"

Comment: Just add `<option>Select Number</option>` as the first option ....

Comment: @Baba one more only question : Is there any other way without using JavaScript only by using php ?

Comment: PHP runs on server while JavaScript Runs on Browsers or Nodejs server .. if you want to use only PHP you would have to separate the pages  and post to the other page with submit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18265/discussion-between-su-sha-and-baba)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$displayTimes` must be set in order to use it. If `$_REQUEST["countIt"]` isn't set, then `$displayTimes` isn't set.

Change it to the following:

```
$displayTimes = isset($_REQUEST['countIt']) ? $_REQUEST['countIt'] : 0;
```

This way, if `$_REQUEST['countIt']` isn't set it won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more clean code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['countIt'])) {
  print '<div class="centrer">';
  $s = "Hello World! <br/>";
  for($i=0; $i<$_GET['countIt']; ++$i) echo $s;
  print '</div>';
}
?>
```

And check this JS code: http://jsfiddle.net/xPuEN/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I sill have the problem that when I select the "1" Value it does anything, and also when I select other value the selected value in the select box still the value "1"